# How do I traverse through a linked list faster?

Tags: c, linked-list, traversal, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to solve a problem which wants me to use doubly circular linked list as the container. I want to traverse through k nodes and erase the k'th node like this:

```
        for(j = 0; j < k; j++){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->prev->next = temp->next;
        temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
```

afterwards I free the node this way:

```
        temp2 = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        free(temp2);
```

Now this codes works fine, but the problem lies when I try to delete nodes of a linked list that contains a huge number of nodes.

The only problem here is the line

```
temp = temp->next
```

takes a while to complete, is there anyway for me to traverse faster?
One solution that I thought of is to skip nodes while traversing like this:

```
temp - temp->next->next
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: That is one of the main drawbacks of a linked list. If traversal/search speed is what you need then you may need to pick a different data structure. There may be specific optimisations such as sorting the list and have "skip" pointers that jump a certain number of nodes. But that is getting more complicated and may or may not meet your needs.

Comment: Note `temp->next->next` doesn't help at all. It's still the same number of traversals.

Comment: Maybe you have a different problem than you think. If `k` is much greater than the number of nodes in your circular list, you'll be losing time by running in circles passing several times the node that you eventually will delete. You must reduce the value of `k` so it is not greater than the number of nodes in the list (hint: modulo).

Comment: @kaylum I see, I guess I cant cheat the linked list iteration time complexity

Comment: @trincot I tried your method and it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your solution takes too much time, it might not be related with the number of nodes in the list, but the value of `k`:

If `k` is much greater than the number of nodes in your circular list, you'll be losing time by running in circles passing several times the node that you eventually will delete. You must reduce the value of `k` so it is not greater than the number of nodes in the list (hint: modulo).